# NSTimer is not fired in React Native component

Tags: ios, react-native

I have an React-Native component. I want to schedule a NSTime but it's never fired and `sendIt` is never called

```
- (void)sendEvent {  
  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(setndIt:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)sendIt:(NSTimer *)timer {
  NSLog(@"Event fired");
}
```

Comment: I had a [similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41755271/timer-doesnt-work-in-native-react-native-component/41774767) in swift and I was able to solve it by starting the timer on the main thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution**: 
It's due to how React Native works with `NSRunLoop`.
You need to add NSTimer to `mainRunLoop`

```
- (void)sendEvent {        
  NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.5 target:self selector:@selector(sendIt:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
  [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}

- (void)sendIt:(NSTimer *)timer {
  NSLog(@"Event fired");
}
```