# Timer doesn't work in native react-native component

Tags: swift, react-native

In my JavaScript, I'm calling a `start` method on some swift code:

```
import {NativeModules} from "react-native";

// somewhere in JS
NativeModules.MyTestClass.start();
// somewhere else I'm listening for events from the swift code
const myModule = new NativeEventEmitter(NativeModules.MyTestClass);
const subscription = myModule.addListener("testEvent", message => {
  console.log(message);
});
```

Swift code:

```
import Foundation

@objc(MyTestClass)
class MyTestClass: RCTEventEmitter {
  let testEventName = "testEvent"

  override func supportedEvents() -> [String]! {
    return [testEventName]
  }

  @objc func start() -> Void {
    let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(
        timeInterval: 0.1,
        target: self,
        selector: #selector(self.update),
        userInfo: nil,
        repeats: true)
    RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)
  }

  @objc func update() {
    print("test")
    self.sendToJs(message: "test")
  }

  @objc private func sendToJs(message: String) -> Void {
    self.sendEvent(withName: testEventName, body: message)
  }
}
```

...which starts up a timer and then, in this example, repeatedly sends the same message to my JavaScript code listening for the event.

**Problem:** The `update` method is never called even when adding the timer to the main run loop as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915024/nstimer-is-not-fired-in-react-native-component).

Is there a simple mistake I'm making here? I'm new to swift.

If not, I'll have to move the timer to JS then repeatedly call the swift code for the data... I'd rather not do that because in my real scenario the timer sending back data is conditional, but I guess doing that is not too bad...

Comment: Try adding `timer.fire()` after adding it to the runloop.

Comment: @ebby94 that will fire the timer once. I hit a breakpoint inside `update` and then it sends the message to the JS, but yeah.. only once.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Figured it out. The timer needs to be setup on the main thread for some reason and no need to add it to the main run loop.

This can be done by changing the `start` function to the following:

```
@objc func start() -> Void {
  DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
    Timer.scheduledTimer(
      timeInterval: 0.1,
      target: self,
      selector: #selector(self.update),
      userInfo: nil,
      repeats: true)
  })
}
```

Comment: I was trying to figure it out why my timer didn't work (native module) and now i found your comment and it start working! Thank you!! ;)